# Which method in OpenCV to use for matching logos on white background?

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to find out which company logos are similar. My images are all the same size with white background. To compare images, I used the ORB matcher, which seemed promising at the time. But logos have very sharp edges, and I think the matcher gets confounded by that geometry, so it matches features that are essentially not the same. If comparing two same images, the features are matched correctly, so it's not a coding problem.
Here's an image of wrongly matched pairs for illustration.

[image: wrongly matched pairs]

Should i proceed with template matching? Or would sometning like this:
[Video Input with OpenCV and similarity measurement](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-input-psnr-ssim/video-input-psnr-ssim.html#videoinputpsnrmssim)
be better?

Or maybe I should just subdivide images in grids of histograms, and run K-means on resulting vectors?

Thanks for your kind answers!

Answer (score 0):

Adding geometrical verification would help a lot.
You can use findHomography, it will work, but if you want better results you'll need to compute a more restricted transformation (such as translation + scale)